# I need to make calculation sheet but the calculate button not working and calculate my inputs here is my formala ((P*D)/(2*SMYS*DF*T*E))

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate this formula (P*D)/(2*SMYS*DF*T*E) but when I click calculate Botton nothing happens (ps: I am not an expert )
I put the input and then I click calculate put no answer.
I made some changes on the code but still not working . please can someone edit the code!

```
<body>
<label for="formulas">Choose a formula:</label>
<select name="formulas" id="formulas">
  <option value="free">Pipeline Thickness</option>
</select>
<h2>Enter inputs</h2>
  <label for="P">MAOP=</label>
  <input type="number" id="P" name="P">
  <br>
  <label for="D=">Do=</label>
  <input type="number" id="D" name="D" >
  <br>
  <label for="SMYS">SMYS=</label>
  <input type="number" id="SMYS" name="SMYS">
  <br>
  <label for="DF">DF=</label>
  <input type="number" id="DF" name="SMYS">
  <br>
  <label for="T">T=</label>
  <input type="number" id="T" name="T">
  <br>
  <label for="E">E &#8521;=</label>
  <input type="number" id="E" name="E &#8521;=" >
  <br>  
  <button type="button" onclick="calculate">calculate</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('calculate').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var amount = document.getElementById("P").value;
  var amount = +P;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("D").value;
  var quantity = +D;
  var amount = document.getElementById("SMYS").value;
  var amount = +SMYS;
  var amount = document.getElementById("DF").value;
  var amount = +DF;
  var amount = document.getElementById("T").value;
  var amount = +T;
  var amount = document.getElementById("E").value;
  var amount = +E;
  var total = (P * D) / (2 * SMYS * DF * T * E);
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
});
    </script>
    </head>
    </body>
    </html>
    </form>
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything on-click, your script will run immediately on load. Also, those variables (`P`, `D`, `SMYS`, `DF`, `T`, `E`) don't appear to be defined anywhere. I would suggest searching for: "click event listener" and "get value from HTML input" as a starting point (both topics have been covered in detail in other questions)

Comment: Also, the HTML `for` attribute should match the `id` of the input you're labelling, not the `name`.